# res.redirect not working after Node.js Express & Passport.js authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have a problem with page redirect with res.redirect().

Here's my code snippet.

`console.log('user=', req.user);` - This is working. After this, page is loading but still in loading. Timeout error occurs.

`res.redirect('/chat/loginsuccess');` - This isn't working.

Does anyone experience this issue before? Please help me.

```
...
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('chat-login'), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('user=', req.user);
    return res.redirect('/chat/loginsuccess');
});

...
passport.use('chat-login', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password'
}, function(email, password, done) {
    if (email) {
        // Use lower-case e-mails to avoid case-sensitive e-mail matching
        email = email.toLowerCase();
    }

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {
        ChatUser.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            // if there are any errors, return the error
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            // if no user is found, return the message
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No User Found.' });
            }

            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Oops! Wrong Password.' });
            }

            // success
            return done(null, user);
        });
    });

}));
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. The problem was in `passport.deserializeUser()`.

Here's my `passport.deserializeUser()` code snippet.

-Old code

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (user != null) {
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            User.findById(id, function(err, admin) {
                if (user != null) {
                    done(null, user);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

-Updated code

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        if (user != null) {
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            ChatUser.findById(id, function(err, admin) {
                done(err, admin);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that when user is null, there was no `done()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the successRedirect and failureRedirect options of passport.

Your login route will look something like:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('chat-login', {
                                             successRedirect : '/whereEverYouWantIfsuccessfullyLoggedIn',
                                             failureRedirect : '/whereEverYouWantIffailedToLogIn'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know, I already did it. But it's same as my code. The result is same.